# JAXB xs:maxLength and minOccurs="0" didn't show in generated class by xsd

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have different complex type in a xsd schema And I use Jaxb to rapresent this on java class. I have rapresented  with sucess complextype enumeration in a javaclass in this way:

```
<xs:element name="SistemaEmissione" type="SistemaEmissione" />
<xs:simpleType name="SistemaEmissione">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="1"/>
<xs:enumeration value="P"/>
<xs:enumeration value="G"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

but I can't rapresent this restriction in java generated class

```
<xs:element name="Master" minOccurs="0">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="15"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Both  minOccurs="0" and maxLength value="15" was sown in generated java class.

Can Anyone help me? tnx

Answer (score 0):

### minOccurs="0"

`minOccurs` is captured in the `required` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#required()

### xs:maxLength

This will not be captured in the metadata.  If you want your object data to be validated you can set an instance of `Schema` on your `Marshaller` or `Unmarshaller`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Tnx very much I try with validation Handler in marshall phase

Comment: But How  I do if I don't want include a node that not respect maxLength in final xml result?